# Pytorch batch row-wise application of function

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, parallel-processing, pytorch

I would like to figure out a way to apply a function which calculates pairwise distances, let's call it dists(A, B), row-wise for every input element in a batch, meaning:

(100, 16, 3) -- input, 100 is the batch size so 100 instances, 16 is let's say image size, and 3 filters (asking for Conv2D)

(5, 3) -- tensor for which I want to calculate the row-wise distance (assume it's A in dists(A, B) and is fixed)

Now, for every instance I am supposed to get back a matrix of shape (5, 16). Naturally, I could use a *for* to span the batch and get my final (100,5,16) result. However, I would love to know if there is an easier way to apply my function row-wise, in parallel, using GPU.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we are using the L1 distance:

```py
import torch
# data and target
a = torch.randn(100, 16, 3)
b = torch.randn(5, 3)

# Reshape the tensors
a = a.unsqueeze(1)
b = b.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(2)

print(a.shape, b.shape)

# Compute distance
dist = (a-b).abs().sum(3)
print(dist.shape)
```

Comment: Well, we're not supposed to reply thanks in comments but, hey thanks a lot. Now I can speed up the whole process by a lot.